# ddd: logic that spans multiple models, where should it go?

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design, ddd-service

I am working on an system and am trying to utilize ddd with node.js.  Here is the an example for the system, from a high-level:

```
database tables(mongoldb):    
user    
username: String    
firstName: String    
middleName: String    
lastName: String    

department
title: String    
members: [{    
    user: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user’},    
    permissions: String    
}]    

patient   
user: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user’},    
department: [{type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: ‘department’}]    

lab: [{    
    patient: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: ‘patient’}    
    doctor: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user’},    
    type: String,    
    results: {there is a lot going on here, }    
}]

medication: [{    
    patient: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: ‘patient’}    
    doctor: {type: this.mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user’},    
    name: String,    
    dosage: Number,    
    etc.    
}]
```

The business logic states that only the patient or a doctor that is a member of one of the departments in the patients, department list can review his medical information.  I initially thought it should be in a separate domain Service as it appears to span entities, but the downside is that would require other services to call a permission service and I thought services should not call other services.  If I placed in the lab and medication entities then I am duplication code and violating dry.  If I add to the departments domain Service then I am making a service call another service.  From a ddd perspective, where does logic like this belong?

Comment: Application services shouldn't call upon other application services because they are use case entry points, but there is no limit on how many domain services you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea services should not call other services.  Security usually is a separate service or whatever.